# access Stimulus JS from rails RJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs, stimulusjs

Is there a way how to access Stimulus JS controller action from Rails RJS view ?

e.g.:

```
//app/views/posts/create.js.erb`
$('#tags').hide();
```

I could do

```
//app/javascripts/controllers/my_stimuous_controller
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'
export default class extends Controller {

  hideElementAction(event) {
    //....
  }
}


//app/views/posts/create.js.erb`
myStimulousController.callAction('hideElementAction');
```

> for those who don't know what  RJS is: "ruby-to-js" template system in Ruby on Rails

Comment: Emit an event from your js.erb view and make the controller listen to it in its initialize function. It’s possible to communicate *between* Stimulus controllers, but I don’t think it’s helpful in your case, since you still need to reference the Stimulus application instance. See this for more details: https://github.com/stimulusjs/stimulus/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

No. Instead, add the action to the element, and fire on it. Here's an example using `hide` as the event, but you can name it anything you like.

```
<div id="tags" 
     data-controller="my-stimulus-controller" 
     data-action="hide->my-stimulus-controller#hideElementAction">
</div>


Rails.fire(document.querySelector("#tags"), 'hide')
```